# How can I retrieve a list<Object> fron firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

[image]

I want to get a List from firebase matrix.
If I print the list I should have [{name1, lat1, long1}, {name2, lat2,long2},...]

Here is my UserModel class

```
@JsonSerializable()
class UserData {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final List<Location> location;

  UserData(
      {required this.uid,
      required this.name,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.location});

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserDataToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Location {
  String nameL;
  double lat;
  double long;

  Location(
      {required this.nameL, required this.lat, required this.long});
  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LocationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
}
```

**update**

```
...
 Future<void> update({
    required String name,
    required String lastName,
  }) async {
    userData = UserData(
      uid: userData.uid,
      name: name,
      lastName: userData.lastName,
      location: userData.location,
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userData.uid)
        .update(userData.toJson())
        .then((value) {...;
    });
  }
...
```

When I try to do update , error Instance of Location apears (this is whay I asked about get a List).

Comment: What is the error? doesn't this line give you the list `final List<Location> location;` ?

Comment: no is not, when I try to update  userData I do: userdata.location and I have error Instance if Location

Comment: can you add an example of the `json` and also the error? please

Comment: I edited the question to try to explain what I nedd

Comment: There are a few things I can see for example `.update(userData.toJson())`, this seems to be `.update(userData.toJson)` or here ` userData = UserData(
      uid: userData.uid,
      name: name,
      lastName: userData.lastName,
      location: userData.location,
    );``` are you sure you about `userData.location`? why are referencing to the same object? Can you also paste the error and lines that  error happens?